# Connecting a Leviton light timer w/ 3 way set up

Tags: light, timer

I am trying to connect the Leviton VPT24-1PZ Vizia 24-Hour Programmable Indoor Timer with Astronomical Clock in a 3-way setup w/ LED lights. There was previously another light timer there (prob ~30 years old and couldn't properly keep time). On the other end of the circuit is a light switch.

I am attaching two photos:

1. Wiring going into the existing light switch on the one end. To be honest, I don't care about keeping it if it made the installation of the Leviton timer easier.
2. Wiring from the old light timer, which I am now replacing. I note that it only had the 3 wires coming out of it and wasn't connected to the copper/ground. The Leviton timer has 5 wires coming out of it.

[image]

Comment: The picture of the 3-way switch on the left is inadequate. You can't see which screws are brass and which are black, which is the most important part!  Also that jumper is not normally in 3-way circuits so this circuit has already been modified to accommodate your old timer.  So it is already not a standard 3-way.

Comment: The *travelers* are very important, they are 1 black and 1 red that are in the same cable, and will be on brass screws.  Can you tell us which those are?

Comment: Can you post photos looking into the backs of the respective boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions that came with the timer. Otherwise, look them up online. And make sure your timer and switch can handle LED lighting. This could be a critical point to consider, or not. Also, Which of these two switches takes power from the source, and which of these two switches gives power to the light(s)? Three-way switches typically have three terminals as well as a bond wire or a bond screw for Ground (4 altogether). Not sure why the Leviton would have 5 wires. Check the included specs sheet for clues.

Comment: Chris, I couldn't follow the instructions that came with it - my wires didn't sync up (you can see the different colors in each of the photos), hence the posting. Re which one takes vs gives power, the Leviton timer would be replacing another timer that was already there.

Comment: It sounds like you want to first identify the wires coming out of the box in order to match them with the instructions. Here is one possible method to use: Turn off the breaker, mark which wires go where, undo them from the old switch and then separate the wires and straighten them out to reduce confusion. Cover the ends of exposed wires with marrettes or electrical tape. Next, turn the power back on and use a pigtail tester to see which wire carries power. Mark it with a small piece of black tape (Hot). The remaining wires should be easier to identify by process of elimination.

Comment: One of the three wires in a 3-way is marked "Common" stamped somewhere on the switch. This Common wire either comes from the source (panel) or goes to the lights. The remaining two wires travel between both switches. These are called "travelers". Power travels between the two switches switches on either one traveler or the other. Only one can be Hot at a time, depending on the position of the switch feeding it.

Comment: @DaveL I'm not surprised they didn't match up.  You are unclear on which wires are travelers, plus this 3-way circuit has already been altered.  It's very important to know which black and red wires are in the same cable togther, and know that on both ends.